# Yeshiva Mir Mesechtas

Tags: talmud-gemara, yeshiva-school, mir

What is the Mir Yeshiva’s (Yerushalayim) cycle of mesechtas? What are they learning for next zman? Does the Mir Yeshiva in Brooklyn follow the same cycle?

Comment: I don't know the exact order but Elul zman they are learning Pesachim, and winter zman Bava Basra. They learn BK, BM, BB, Makkos, Yevamos, Kesubos, Nedarim (?), Kiddushin, Pesachim and Sukkah, if I'm not mistaken. It's a five year cycle. Don't know about Brooklyn.

Comment: If you check out Rav Asher Arieli's [page](https://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Ravs.aspx?Lang=Idish&RavID=-1&ROrder=-1&FID=208339&HideMenus=False) on Kol Halashon you see a list of the masechtos he gives shiur on. Apparently they also learn Gittin.

Comment: Mir Brooklyn does not learn the same thing. I don't know what they're learning next zman but when I learned there a few years ago we did not learn the same thing as Mir Yerushalaim